# How to convert returned JSON data from API into DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to convert raw JSON data that is returned from an API into a DataFrame using Pandas, but I'm not having any luck. This is the returned JSON data I am getting using the request module:

```
{
"id": "1MUB48cgb5uy54V_ErhMQzbu-wTRNa-9EVgDbbL4u_30sdQ",
"accountId": "rTtNLALKTnMMbO_BYWRZks9JVS51o1TvSRU3-YQDPlkRsZY",
"puuid": "Ymwm3n3wArC94OnrPDwDuK5nb98fhL4-usc3lZ14UdlbrZqOUHVWmHSh42W6-ICFAIM0LEUYT0RhsA",
"name": "A Catalyst",
"profileIconId": 7,
"revisionDate": 1552276172000,
"summonerLevel": 177
}
```

Now let's say I have the above data stored in a variable, 'r'. I assumed that it would have just been as easy as

```
import pandas as pd

dataFrame = pd.DataFrame(r)
print(dataFrame)
```

But this is not the case, as I receive the error:

```
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

Comment: did you try `pandas.read_json`?

Comment: @bubble - I did try this, but it gives me the error: 'ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'dict'>'. I thought since the JSON data was already in the form of a dictionary that I didn't need to use this, hence what I tried in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

dataFrame = pd.DataFrame.from_records(r)
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html

Comment: Do you have any idea what I should pass into the index parameter? I try passing 0 and I get KeyError: 0.